# Not getting correct path for some points from root node to the point in java

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find out path from root node to a given point by using recursive algorithm. I am getting correct path for some of the points but for some points, I am getting the incorrect path. Please check below link for detailed description about the problem.

[Problem Statement](https://www.docdroid.net/X38NJJZ/problem-statement.docx)

I have tried below code for this [input](https://www.docdroid.net/KNwEZun/input.txt) and [output](https://www.docdroid.net/GEvHkJR/output.txt).

```
public static List<String> findPathToNode(Node rootNode, Point toFind) {
    // @ToDo Implement this routine
    List<String> nodeList = new ArrayList<>();
    if(toFind.getX() < rootNode.getWidth() && toFind.getY() <rootNode.getWidth()){
      return getPath(rootNode, toFind, nodeList);
    }
   return nodeList;
  }

  //Recursive function to loop through all nodes of tree and return empty LinkedList
  // if point not found or NOT Empty with the path to the point, if point is found
  private static List <String> getPath(Node root, Point p, List<String> result) {
    if(p.getX() >-1 && p.getY() >-1) {
      if (root != null) {
        result.add(root.getId());
        List<Node> childNodes = root.getChildren();
        if (childNodes != null && !childNodes.isEmpty()) {
          Node child = null;
          for (Node node : childNodes) {

             (isLeftBoundCondtionMet(node,p) && isTopBoundCondtionMet(node,p)) {
              child = node;
            }
          }
          getPath(child, p, result);
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static Boolean isLeftBoundCondtionMet(Node root, Point p) {
    return root.getLeft() <= p.getX() && (p.getX() < (root.getLeft() + root.getWidth()));
  }

  public static Boolean isTopBoundCondtionMet(Node root, Point p) {
    return root.getTop() <= p.getY() && (p.getY() < (root.getTop() + root.getHeight()));
  }
```

It gives me the following error

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Error in output. Unexpected path for point: java.awt.Point[x=32,y=3] 
Expected :node/node-1/node-1-6/node-1-6-8/node-1-6-8-4
Actual   :node/node-1/node-1-6
```

Comment: I suggest attaching a debugger to this, and walking through a test case that's failing to see what it's doing different from how you expect it to behave. At a glance, the code looks fine. It could be that the inputs are incorrect, or it could be an edge case with the various greater-than, less-than clauses.

Comment: @Welbog please check the edited question. I have attached debugger.

Comment: The error message tells you which test case is failing and also the expected output vs your output. You need to walk through the code on that input to see why it's doing what the test case doesn't expect. It could be that the nodes are not being configured correctly, or one of numerous off-by-one bugs or other issues. You're not going to get an answer from Stack Overflow unless the issue with the code is obvious, and in this case it isn't obvious. Debugging is an important skill, and you need to apply your debugging skill to this problem. I'm sorry I can't be of more help to you.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would guess that the node inputs are wrong - that maybe they're supposed to be stored as relative offsets but they're interpreted by this algorithm as absolutes, something like that.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? @Anamika